# react-native-image-picker installation breaks my app

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

Step 1:  npm install react-native-image-picker
......app is still building fine.....
Step 2: react-native link react-native-image picker
...app no longer compiles

When I clean gradle I get error:
 "*Could not set process working directory to 'C:\code\rn\xs\node_modules\react-native-image-picker\example\android': could not set current directory (errno 3)*"

When I try to rebuild in gradle I also get error:
"*Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-117 to override*".

So I take suggestion of error message and add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to application element.....
I now still get same error when I clean.....but error when I rebuild is a little different:
"*tools:replace specified at line:10 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified.*"
.
Please help!!

Comment: did you try add supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" on build.gradle and npx jetify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As addition for Lenoarod answer, you can use [jetifier library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jetifier).  It will help you to convert all library that hasn't converted to AndroidX.

According to it's documentation

> So now you need to convert your app to AndroidX, but many of your react-native libraries ship native Java code and have not updated. How is this done?
>
> First, use Android Studio's refactoring tool to convert your app re: the Android developer docs
>   1. npm install --save-dev jetifier
>   2. npx jetify
>   3. npx react-native run-android (your app should correctly compile and work)
>   4. Call npx jetify run in the postinstall target of your package.json (Any time your dependencies update you have to jetify again)

Answer (score 1):

your react-native version uses Androix library, but the react-native-image-picker which you installed used android.support.v4. So when you build the project, that error happens. there two ways for this solution Which I suggest.
the one solution is that you update your `react-native-image-picker` version. the new version supports the androix supported library. the following is the [official
guide](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker)

```
To use this library you need to ensure you match up with the correct version of React Native you are using. the flowing is the [official guide][1].

p.s. React Native introduced AndroidX support in 0.60, which is a breaking change for most libraries (incl. this one) using native Android functionality.
```

If you have to use the old version, you can modify the `react-native-image-picker` related files. for example the ImagePickerModule,ImageConfig. they locate in android/src/main folder

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.StyleRes;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both.
lzzuddiin's answer was closest....all I needed to do was "Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX" from the menu bar; that alone solved the issue